# MySQL USE command not working in Visual Studio Code

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-code

I'm running MySQL version 8.0.34 in Visual Studio Code 1.82.0 on a Windows 10 laptop. I'm able to connect to the database and run SQL commands and queries, but for some reason the "USE ;" command isn't working. I get no error message, but the database isn't being selected.

This only happens when running MySQL in Visual Studio Code - The USE command works fine in the MySQL command processor.

The name of the database I'm trying to select is "rpfirst".

1. I ran the SHOW DATABASES; command, which generates a list of all available databases. "rpfirst" was in the list.
2. I ran the SELECT DATABASE(); command to display the currently selected database, and the output was NULL, indicating that no database was selected.
3. I ran the USE rpfirst; command to select the rpfirst database. There was no generated output, but the following output was written to the console:

[Start] Executing MySQL query...
{"fieldCount":0,"affectedRows":0,"insertId":0,"serverStatus":2,"warningCount":0,"message":"","protocol41":true,"changedRows":0}
[Done] Finished MySQL query.

4. I ran the SELECT DATABASE(); command again, and there was still no selected database.
5. I verified this by running a SELECT command with an unqualified table name, and it failed.

Comment: Into which part of VS Code exactly are you entering these commands?

Comment: Not using VS Code - I'm using the mysql command processor from a Windows 10 command processor.

Comment: I just tried this again and it worked. I must have mistyped the USE statement. Sorry for the trouble.